# Get selected ListView Item's ID (data populated with SQLite DB)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

I have a database which keeps track of a user's reminder data (reminder name, notes, date, time, etc.). The first column is it's primary key (_ID). The ListView is populated from the database and it shows a simple set of rows with the reminder's name(s), like so:

---

Take out the trash.

---

Walk the dog.

---

Eat lunch.

---

etc.

---

Now my question is, how do I get my app to figure out which specific reminder has been clicked? When a row is clicked, I need to find its primary key (_ID column) from my database and be able to retrieve all the data in that row.

So far, I know that I need to use a onItemClick to detect the click. But how can I get the primary key value (_ID) of the item that has been clicked? My current code looks like this:

```
final Context context = this;

//DB Connectivity variables.
protected RemindersDAO remindersDAO;
protected SimpleCursorAdapter remindersCursorAdapter;
public ListView viewRemindersListView;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_local_reminders);

    // Get rid of the app title in the action bar.
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    viewRemindersListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_view_local_reminders);

    remindersDAO = new RemindersDAO(this);
    Cursor cursor = remindersDAO.all(this);

    remindersCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                                     R.xml.view_reminders_item_layout,
                                     cursor, new String [] { RemindersDAO.NAME },
                                     new int[] { R.id.view_reminders_item_text } );

    viewRemindersListView.setAdapter(remindersCursorAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long arg3) {
    remindersDAO = new RemindersDAO(this);
    Cursor cursor = remindersDAO.all(this);

    int idColIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(RemindersDAO._ID); 
    int rowId = cursor.getInt(idColIndex); 
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_view_local_reminders, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     //Set the classes that are called from each actionbar item.
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.local_reminders_actionbar_go_advanced:
             Intent i=new Intent(this, AdvancedNewReminder.class);
             startActivity(i);
             return true;
         case R.id.local_reminders_actionbar_simple_reminder:
             Intent k = new Intent(this, QuickNewReminder.class);
             startActivity(k);
             return true;

             /* case R.id.local_reminders_actionbar_google_tasks:
             showGoogleTasksBetaDialog();
             return true; */

     }
     return false;
 }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    return;
}
```

}

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `onItemClick` method you can see 3rd param -`long id` is the `id` in database. So you just simple get that clicked item id

```
  @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long arg3) {
       Log.d("Clicked item id", " "+ arg3); 
    }
```

if you want other fields you should get cursor of clicked item

```
   @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long arg3) {
     Cursor item=   (Cursor) reminderCursorAdapter.getItem(position);
Log.d("Clicked item field", " "+ item.getColum(your colum index)); 
    }
```